# Spring Dependency Injection example project does not have a main class. How can I run it?

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependency-injection

Consider this code GitHub: [Spring Pattern Example Code](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Spring5-Design-Patterns)

If you checkout Chapter3 - Dependency Injection, the project does not have any main class in it.

I did a

> mvn clean install

which was successful.

When I go to execute the jar, I get the below error:

> bash-3.2$ java -jar
>   ./target/Chapter-03-Spring-Dependency-Injection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>   no
>   main manifest attribute, in
>   ./target/Chapter-03-Spring-Dependency-Injection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

How can I run this project? Should I edit the build portion of pom to build as spring-boot? Should I manually add a MANIFEST file?

Comment: There are some output messages which I would like to see when I run the project. Is it possible to run this without a main class?

Comment: Any idea how I can do this? Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its not a complete application that you could run, so you must type some lines to see what's going on , here is what you could do to run examples :

1. import project into your IDE as maven project
2. create Main class with famous static main

if you want to instantiate the config with xml style you could do it as follow

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    TransferService bean = context.getBean(TransferService.class);
    bean.transferAmmount(10l, 10l, new Amount(1000d));
}
```

}

Another approach is to use config file :

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        TransferService bean = context.getBean(TransferService.class);
        bean.transferAmmount(10l, 10l, new Amount(1000d));
    }

}
```

3. run the project as  java application

Comment: I still get the 

"no main manifest attribute, in ./target/Chapter-03-Spring-Dependency-Injection-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" error when I run this as a java project.

Comment: You don't need it at all, simple steps above and that work for me, run the Main class as java-application not the JAR